# Assign text file into a variable

Tags: lua, variable-assignment

Is it possible to assign a text file into a variable and access the file by just calling the variable? If so, how do you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [IO library](http://lua-users.org/wiki/IoLibraryTutorial)

```
local input = assert(io.open(inputfile, "r"))
local data = f:read("*all")
--do some processing to data
local output = assert(io.open(outfule, "w"))
output:write(data)
input:close()
output:close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to do as such from a function. You would have:

```
function writeToFile(_fileName) -- _fileName being the file you want to write to
        local file = io.open(_fileName, "w")
        file:write("This is a string that will be written to the file")
        file:write("This is a second string")
        file:flush( ) -- save the contents
        file:close( ) -- stop accessing the file
end
```

If you only want to read the file then all you need to do is

```
function readFromFile(_fileName)
    local file = io.open(_fileName, "r")
    for line in file:lines() do
       print(""..line.."\n")
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "calling the variable" literally, then try this:

```
local filename="/etc/passwd"
local f=assert(io.open(filename,"r"))
getmetatable(f).__call = f.read

repeat
        local s=f()
        print(s)
until s==nil
```